# Win API function for modifying file permissions

Tags: c, file, winapi, windows-7, file-permissions

I'm searching for a way to modify the file permissions of a file in Windows 7 using C.
For example: I would like to add read permissions for C:\a.txt for the user A,
or remove write permissions from user B.

I have found some functions that are used in linux (Like chmod) but these are no good in windows.

I'm sure a Win API function must exists that does just what I'm searching for, Do anybody see something I'm missing ?

Thanks a lot for your help,
David.

Comment: Look at the [authorization functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are also lots of (non SO) hits if you use your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while ago and, initially, not a pleasant experience, but then I found ATL Security: atlsecurity.h simplifies a lot the work with this stuff.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awt7k7f5(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i notices that there are many functions for different types of structures(SID,ACL,DACL). can you tell me which one of the atlsecurity.h functions works the best for my case?

Comment: I think they (atlsecurity classes) help you building and managing the control lists, but you'll end up by calling `SetSecurityInfo` or `SetNamedSecurityInfo` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `CSid::LoadAccount` should help you find the users A, B

Comment: it looked up CSid::LoadAccount and it its header class is only for c++   is there an alternative for c?

Comment: Ooops, ATL is C++, but why on earth do you strictly need only C ? If it is really a must, then you could do you your code in C++ to test it and and than convert it (ATL is just a C++ thin wrapper, you have all the code visible in the header), but it will be a great pain since you'll have to release all the resources yourself.